# Proving difficulty in MASA

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Prove that $ L^\infty{(\mathbb{R},\mu)}$ is a masa in $B(L^2(\mathbb{R},\mu))$, $\mu$ is sigma finite measure in particular Lebesgue, and what is the cyclic vector of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any function that is essentially nonzero is both cyclic and separating. In particular this proves that $L^\infty(\mathbb R,\mu)$ is a masa.

For instance, let 
$$
f(t)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \tfrac1{|n|}\,1_{[n,n+1]}.
$$
Then, for any $g\in L^2$ bounded with compact support contained in $[-m,m]$, let 
$$
h=\sum_{n=-m}^m|n|\,g\,1_{[n,n+1]}\in L^\infty;
$$
then $hf=g$. As bounded functions of compact support are dense in $L^2$, $f$ is cyclic. And if $h\in L^\infty$ and $hf=0$, then $h=0$ a.e., so $f$ is separating.

Comment: i know what nasa is. what's masa

Comment: Maximal abelian sub-algebra. It's a completely standard term in von Neumann algebras, and likely also in C$^*$-algebras.

Comment: Sir, if I decompose the $\mathbb{R}$ into disjoint unions of $E_{n}$ such that $\mu_{E_n}$ is finite naming $\mu_{n}=\text{ restriction of }\mu \text{ on }E_{n}$, can I tell that the algebra $L^\infty{(\mathbb{R},\mu)}$ is direct sum of masas hense masa?

Comment: Yes, that should work if you prove that a direct sum of masas is a masa.